# Pig Latin Filter by list of strings

Tags: filter, apache-pig

I have a file containing urls
and 3 files that contain urls that I want to see if they exist in the first file

Example of first file is

http://www.url1.com/xxxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/,

http://www/urln.com/zzz/zzz/zzz/zzzz/zzzz/zz

example of filter files:

**filter1**

url1.com

url2.com

**filter2**

url5.com

url6.com/ddfd

urlx.org

What I want to do is that on the same pass (if possible) check if **any** url from filter1 or **any** of the urls in filter 2 and so on is in the first file and if it is write the match to a file named after that filter( filter name irrelevant).
Important each filter

output will be something like this

filter1.out

http:// www.url1.com/xxx/sss
http:// www.url2.com/xxx/xxxx/xxxx

Comment: Please post what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give a high level description of what I'd do in your shoes:

1. Load up all files as data sets. We can call them urls, filter1, filter2, and filter3
2. If I understand correctly, there's no difference between the three filters, so just UNION them together as a new data set we'll call big_filter.
3. JOIN urls with big_filter using a regex to extract the base url from urls. REGEX_EXTRACT is a built-in Pig function. The inner join will get rid of all items in url that are not in a filter.
4. GENERATE just the url column from the resulting data set.
5. Run a DISTINCT on the data set that was generated in step 4.
6. Store the data set generated in step 5 using one of the various pig STORE functions in whatever form you like best.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that filter files fit into memory on compute nodes - use Perl or other favorite language for matching and stream data through this filter, e.g.:

```
DEFINE MY_FILTER ` perl $script $filter1 $filter2 filter3 ` SHIP('$script','$filter1', '$filter2', '$filter3');
A = load '$input';
B = stream A through MY_FILTER;
store B into '$output';
```

This runs in one pass. 
Call this Pig script from a bash script that defines $filter and other parameters.
Implement string matching and output in the $script which will load $filter1, $filter2 and $filter3, do matching from STDIN and produce output in the desired format.